# Trouble understanding what the final call in a recursive algorithm returns, algorithm example provided

Tags: java, recursion

So I have this pseudocode algorithm I was given for an interview which traverses a binary tree and returns a value of some sort. After tracing the algorithm with a drawn out binary tree, I kept second guessing myself on whether I return *`2 + valOne + valTwo` on the final call when the algorithm returns back to the root*, or not. When I did apply that, the number returned was 2*(height of the tree) by my calculations, and I wanted to check if my answer and logic was correct.
The answer according to the practice sheet claims that it counts the number of edges in a tree but I don't understand at all how that is possible.

```
public int foo(r){
         if(r is leaf) return 0;
         else{
             valOne = foo(r.leftChild());
             valTwo = foo(r.rightChild());
             return 2 + valOne + valTwo;
         }
```

So is `return 2 + valOne + valTwo` is applied on the root of the entire tree also? And if it is, would my answer not be correct? 
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a binary tree whose every non-leaf node has both a left and a right child node, this does count the number of edges.

```
valOne = foo(r.leftChild()); // count edges in left subtree

valTwo = foo(r.rightChild()); //count edges in right subtree

return 2 + valOne + valTwo; // 2  (the edges from this node to its children) + edges in sub trees
```

```
if(r is leaf) return 0; //leaf nodes have no edges pointing out
```

Comment: What if we have a non-balanced binary tree?

Comment: It works for non-balanced trees as well, as long as each node has 2 children, correcting the amswer. The first node that doesn't have both children and isn't a leaf could result in a null pointer exception unless handled.

Answer (score 0):

With the provided pseudocode, if it is a tree like the one in attached graph, the value of each node will be justified as described in the graph.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is not valid java code.

Let's try to understand what you're trying to ask. Perhaps you meant this snippet:

```
public int foo(Node r) {
    if (r instanceof Leaf) return 0;
    int valOne = foo(r.leftChild());
    int valTwo = foo(r.rightChild());
    return 2 + valOne + valTwo;
}
```

the line `int valOne = ...` invokes this very method again, this time on the left child. And if the left child is not a leaf, during the execution of this method on the left child, it, too, would invoke itself yet again for its children.

The return statement isn't the interesting one and does not engage in recursion whatsoever. It's the `valOne =` and `valTwo =` lines.